# Quasar Table save sorting to return to same sorted page

Tags: javascript, vue.js, sorting, quasar-framework

When using Quasar Table and user sorting by column and/or search ("all Item table" page). Then select an item to edit. This loads the "item edit page". When the user goes back to the "all Item table" page we want the "all Item table" page to be sorted as it was when the user left the page.

Where do I find the data in the quasar table about the sorting so that I can save it? The sorting is done by clicking on the header and I expect there is data saved on the sorting. how do I access the sorting data or do I need to generate custom code separately for the table to use later?

Any ideas?

```
<q-table
  dense
  v-model:selected="selected"
  :loading="loading"
  :title="tableTitle"
  :rows="rows"
  row-key="dvirDate"
  :columns="columns"
  :filter="filter"
  :rows-per-page-options="[15, 30, 60, 100, 0]"
  @row-click="onRowClick"
  selection="multiple"
>
//with multiple columns like:
 {
name: "user",
label: "Driver",
field: "user",
align: "left",
sortable: true,
```

},

Comment: The q-table code doesn't really offer any insight here.  It really depends on the architecture of the app.  Saving/loading settings from global state seems like the obvious solution.  If going "back" involves a full page load or refresh, you may need to use localStorage.  Depending on the relationship between components maybe you can get away with just props/events.

Comment: I changed all the filtering to sorting. How to save and remember the sorting , thanks

Comment: Filtering or sorting, either way, my previous comment still applies... Pick what solution works best based on how your app works.  It mainly depends on how the navigation works between the two pages, which you've not given any information about.  I don't know anything about your app but I would GUESS that saving/loading from global state would be a fine solution. You can roll your own or use something like [Pinia](https://pinia.vuejs.org/)

Comment: OK, thanks for your reply. I was hoping for a general answer. To change to a specific question. Where do I find the data in the quasar table about the sorting so that I can save it? The sorting is done by clicking on the header and I expect there is data saved on the sorting. how do I access the sorting data or do I need to generate custom code separately for the table to use later?